# Can the built-in "Component" component be used in a render function?

Tags: vue.js

Is it possible to use the [`<component>`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#component) component in a render function?  I am getting the following error trying to use it:

> Unknown custom element: <component> - did you register the component
> correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name"
> option.

Both `<component>` and `<transition>` are listed as [Built-In Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Built-In-Components) and I have successfully used `<transition>` within a render function, but I am getting the error above when using `<component>`.

I wanted to use the `<component>` component since it allows you to work with the `<transition>` element [so painlessly](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transitioning-Between-Components).

---

**This works:**

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      cmp: "foo"
    }
  },
  created() {
    setInterval(() => this.cmp = (this.cmp === "foo" ? "bar" : "foo"), 2000);
  },
  components: {
    foo: {
      template: "<div>foo</div>"
    },
    bar: {
      template: "<div>bar</div>"
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <component :is="cmp"></component>
</div>
```

**This does not:**

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      cmp: "foo"
    }
  },
  created() {
    setInterval(() => this.cmp = (this.cmp === "foo" ? "bar" : "foo"), 2000);
  },
  components: {
    foo: {
      template: "<div>foo</div>"
    },
    bar: {
      template: "<div>bar</div>"
    }
  },
  render(h) {
    return h("div", [
      h("component", {
        props: {
          is: this.cmp
        }
      })
    ]);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the ease of `<transition>` use is not predicated on the use of `<component>`.  If you want to set up a [transition between components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transitioning-Between-Components) in a render function, you just need to change the element that you return under the transition.  See the example below.

I have a feeling that I was overthinking what the `<component>` actually is.  The Vue API likely considers everything defined through `Vue.component()` or `Vue({components: {})` "components".  Considering that, there is no reason to outright use `<component>` within a render function.

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      cmp: "foo"
    }
  },
  created() {
    setInterval(() => this.cmp = (this.cmp === "foo" ? "bar" : "foo"), 2000);
  },
  components: {
    foo: {
      template: "<div>foo</div>"
    },
    bar: {
      template: "<div>bar</div>"
    }
  },
  render(h) {
    return h("div", [
      h("transition", {
        props: {
          appear: true,
          name: "fade",
          mode: "out-in"
        }
      }, [h(this.cmp)])
    ]);
  }
});
```

```css
.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity 500ms ease;
}

.fade-enter,
.fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```